# Launch your own application starting the camera app

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm just looking a way to launch/open an application automatically every time the camera app starts! I know it will something to do with intent. Does someone has some examples to forward to me? I'd also like to add a toggle withing my application settings to enable/disable automatic launch on camera app opening.

Thanks allot, Diego

Comment: That is not supported, sorry.

Comment: That's bad. I was thinking it was possible seeing for example the app Musixmatch, that starts automatically the floating lyrics (of the song) whenever you open Spotify or YouTube. I was thinking it was possible to do kinda the same with the camera app. Thanks in any case for your reply. Diego

Comment: "the app Musixmatch, that starts automatically the floating lyrics (of the song) whenever you open Spotify or YouTube" -- what they are doing should not be reliable on Android 5.0+. Google is going to great lengths to block apps from knowing what other apps are in the foreground, for privacy and security reasons. Perhaps this app is exploiting some security flaws, flaws that hopefully will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you give an example of an app that does something similar to what you described, then maybe we could understand what you mean if we misunderstood.

The fact is, if I understand your question correctly, you want your app to start whenever a user hits starts the camera app on android.

As CommonsWare noted, this is not supported. It would require you to have control over the code behind the Camera app, and even then I'm not sure if you can start other apps from a given app (I believe you can, as I've seen this behavior before)

Short answer is: you can't. You might be able to start the camera app from your app however, but that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Jacob for this information. It means that if I can go on that way, I'll proceed launching the camera app within my app. Thanks again. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: Can you mark my post as the correct answer if it helped you solve your problem? Glad I could help!